# how to get the form data in JSON format in servlet

Tags: javascript, java, json

My html code is

```
<form action="/FirstServlet/Profile" method="post"  class="login">
    UserName: <input type="text"  id="uName" name="name"><p>
    Password: <input type="password"  id="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="login">
</form>
```

and the javascript code is

```
<script  src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script  src="js/jquery.serializeObject.js"></script>
<script  src="js/Gruntfile.js"></script> 
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
            var form=$('form.login').serializeObject();
            alert(form);
            form.submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:form.attr('method'),
                    url:form.attr('action'),
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:Json.stringify(form),
                    success:function(data){

                    }
                });
            });

        });
</script>
```

But still I get the answer in this format

```
name=zeeshan&password=zeeshan@123
```

I want to get the answer in json format like:

```
{"name":"zeeshan","password":"zeeshan@123"}
```

My servlet code of getting the data

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));


    String json = "";
    if(br != null){
        json = br.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

I've searched a lot, every where they say that the output of this code is in json, but practically I didn't get it in that format.

How can I get my output to be in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are stringifying it before sending, that could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

You may try this workaround, in javascript:

```
 data:{'json':JSON.stringify($(form).serializeArray())},
```

In servlet:

```
String json=request.getParameter("json");
```

**Edited:**

```
 data:{'json':JSON.stringify($(form).serializeObject())},
```

Comment: data:{'json':JSON.stringify($(form).serializeObject())},

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="login">
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="login">
```

Clicking on input type submit, submits the form directly and reloads the page and hence your script is never called.